# Not able to fetch menu data with WPGQL

Tags: wordpress, graphql, next.js

I am using the `graphql-request` npm package. It is working fine for all page, and post requests, but I am not able to get the menu data.

When I do it within the IDE it returns the data as expected, however, when I call it from the Next.js client it is returning `null`.

This is the request:

```js
const response = await graphcms.request(`
  query MyQuery {
    menu(idType: NAME, id: "navbar") {
      id
      name
      menuItems {
        nodes {
          url
          title
          label
        }
      }
    }
  }
`);
```

Any ideas what can be causing this to work in the IDE but not fetching on an external request? I did not see any options for settings.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered this is because menus require  locations. Since I had  created a theme that simply redirected to my Next deployment, it did not include any menu locations.

You can follow these instructions to add menu locations to a theme:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/adding-a-new-menu-location/